# How to find the implementation code of a vanilla JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, if-statement

A colleague and I were discussing the implementation of the JavaScript "if" statement and I wanted to find the implementation so we could read through it and hopefully get a bit wiser.

However, I wasn´t able to find it anywhere, so my question is; Where do you go to read the JavaScript source code?

Comment: if is not a function, it's a statement defined in the javascript spec and implemented by the engine like blink, so you could look for the code of a particular engine like blink

Comment: There are numerous JavaScript compilers available, all with different source code, some of which is open and some of which is not. Questions seeking recommendations for off-site resources are explicitly off-topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I think it is a good question, no need to downvote it. The answer to this question and discussion can help people understand the language and the surrounding ecosystem more.

Comment: @kodeaben please see edits to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` is not a function but is a keyword. There is no JavaScript implementation of it.

The compiler/transpiler understands the `if` statement just like it understands other tokens from the `var`, `const`, and `let` to `do {} while();` and `for`. All of these are keywords with special meaning known to the JavaScript interpreter.

You would want to look the implementation of the interpreter/compiler and runtime implementation to understand how it handles the various control keywords such as if. Alternatively you can look at the specs of the language.

Edit:

It is worth noting that JavaScript is ECMAScript. There are ECMAScript standards and JavaScript implements these. So concepts such as truthiness and falsiness (whether a value is truthy of falsey) is in the ECMAScript standards.

Particularly, you can check section 13.6.7 that speaks to the semantics of the `if` statement: https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-if-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation

From there, one can find what it means for something to be truthy/falsey, which is `ToBoolean`, as defined in the specs (not a JavaScript function):

[image]

Comment: "There is no JavaScript implementation of it." — That's flat out wrong. There are several JavaScript runtimes written in JS. The question isn't asking for a the `if` source code to be written in JS anyway.

Comment: @Quentin There is no JavaScript `if` statement implemented in some JavaScript library that your JavaScript code references. That's what I meant to say.

I didn't say that a JavaScript runtime/interpreter etc implementation cannot be implemented in a general language such as JavaScript.